# Html form method inside Asp.net form not posting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, handler

I am trying to post data using javascript to generic handler but I am unable to upload.

Can anyone suggest me where I am going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

         function postdata() {
             var fieldValue = document.getElementById("field1").value;
             postwith("Upload.ashx", { field1: fieldValue });
         }

         function postwith(to, p) {
             var myForm = document.createElement("form");
             myForm.method = "post";
             myForm.action = to;
             for (var k in p) {
                 var myInput = document.createElement("input");
                 myInput.setAttribute("name", k);
                 myInput.setAttribute("value", p[k]);
                 myForm.appendChild(myInput);
             }
             document.body.appendChild(myForm);
             myForm.submit();
             document.body.removeChild(myForm);
         }

</script>
```

This is the actual thing I need to do with Form:

```
<form id="Form1" action="Upload.ashx" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data"
    runat="server">
```

As I am having a master page I need to do this way:

```
  <button type="submit" class="start"  OnClientClick="postdata(); return false;">
                Start upload</button>
```

Comment: Have you looked with Firefox/Firebug to see if the request is being sent? Or if there are any javascript errors?  What's up with the `multipart/form-data` -- are you trying to upload a file?

Comment: No the request is not happening and No javascript errors.

Comment: It looks like a normal html button so probably you want to go with a `onClick=` instead of `OnClientClick=`

Comment: when myForm.submit(); is executed, isn't it moving user out of your page to another one?

Comment: yes it's showing me the upload.ashx handler page

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the form approach, consider using XmlHttpRequest: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro2/

If you are using JQuery or Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX frameworks, there are helpers to make this much, MUCH easier (JQuery with `$.ajax` and ASP.NET AJAX with `Sys.Net.WebRequest` I believe).

Comment: Can you be more clear for the above sample how do I modify it?

Comment: `XmlHttpRequest` does not work for `multipart/form-data` form. `FormData` object can help, but it is not implemented in all browsers.